# Property 'value' does not exist on type '{}' Angular

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am using angular and angular fire2. At the time of running the server, I received the following error. but everything works, when I start the server, I have to delete the ".service" and save the changes, then I put it back and it works.

```
private afs: AngularFirestore

this.afs.doc('service/' + res.category).valueChanges().subscribe((response) => {
         this.categories = Object.values(response.service);
        });
```

> **Error:** Property 'service' does not exist on type '{}'